# Generate Random Sentence

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create random sentences. I can't create any lists or populate anything myself. I will end up asking questions that analyze the sentence's words.

I don't understand how to use PHP to arrange verbs and nouns to create complete sentences.

***I'm not asking for an external reference***, just how to use PHP to generate random sentences.

Is it possible to grab a sentence of a web page and test to see if it is grammatically correct?

Thanks!

Comment: What? You want us to write an intelligent english speaking robot on SO for you?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Of course you can check whether a sentence is correct or not. Use the links in my answer to understand how sentences are built. Then you can load the word lists into your database.
Because you know the order you can check every word's part of speech against your entries in your database.
Example: John Clara often comes late to class.
You search in the database for John. Then you know that this is a subject and this can be the beginning. The second one is also a subject and so its wrong in place -> no correct sentence.
If you have specific questions about this you can ask them on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this [site](http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/word-lists.html) you will get your wordlists. If you separately load them into your database, you can save the part of speech too.

[Simple english grammar](http://esl.fis.edu/learners/advice/syntax.htm) helps you building the sentence ;)

Oh, I'm sorry. Did not read that you want *meaningful* sentences.

---

You can use the tips above to check the grammar of the sentences too ;)